# Как понять, к чему относится слово "вероятно"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, вводные-слова

**К тому же Matlab, вероятно, вычисляет быстрее.**

Как понять, к чему относится слово *вероятно* в предложении: *вероятно Matlab* или *вероятно вычисляет быстрее*?

Мне встречалось правило, будто можно не ставить запятую после *вероятно*, тогда *вероятно* будет относиться к *вычисляет быстрее*.
Существует ли такое правило?

Comment: Предположение, о котором говорится здесь и настоящее время сказуемого несочетаются. Стало быть — «К тому же Matlab, вероятно вычислит быстрее».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В предложении утверждается, что Matlab считает быстрее [чем Mathematica, например]. Следовательно, "вероятно" относится ко всему этому утверждению, делая его менее категоричным. Это [вводное слово](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=83#pp83) и оно должно выделяться запятыми (см. § 91 по ссылке).

Иначе происходит выделение в следующем случае (см. подробности по той же ссылке):

> § 93. Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т. е. запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом...

В Вашем предложении нет обособления.

**Upd.**

Вот пример, в котором запятая не нужна (объяснение [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=285#pg285)):

**Matlab считает быстро, вероятно быстрее других программных продуктов.**

Answer (score 1):

А чтобы «вероятно» относилось к «Matlab», думаю, достаточно будет поменять порядок слов в предложении:

***Быстрее вычисляет, вероятно, Matlab.***

Хм, может, вообще «вероятно» относится к тому, что следует за ним?..